# Sql how to select where day and month between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select where day and month between two dates :

for example : 31/December is between 26/December/2016 and 02/January/2017

my query :

```
select table2.*
from table1,
     table2
where table2.day between DAYOFMONTH(table1.date_start) and DAYOFMONTH(table1.date_end)
  and table2.month between MONTH(table1.date_start) and MONTH(table1.date_end)
```

table1 (reservation) :

**-id -date_start (date) -date_end (date)**

1 | 2016-12-26 | 2017-01-02

table2: (recipe)

**id | name | day (int) | month (int)**

1  | xxx  | 31     | 12

Comment: Column day's data type? Tag the dbms you're using. (Some non-ANSI SQL there.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Looks like MySQL.

Comment: I use mysql database :
table1 : 
-id
-date_start (date)
-date_end (date)

table2:
- id
- day (int)
- month (int)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why aren't you joining those two tables?

Comment: He is joining the tables. (Old style syntax.)

Comment: @ALWAN 1 row in each table does ***not*** constitute "sample" data. Not to mention the total lack of ***desired results***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using MySQL.  Rather than trying to check the months and days separately, instead just use `BETWEEN` with the two points whose range you wish to capture.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.some_col = t2.some_col
WHERE day_col BETWEEN '2016-12-26' AND '2017-01-02'
```

Note that I also added a join condition to your query, without which you would be doing a cross join, most likely not what you intend.

Comment: i have two cols day_col and month_col

Comment: Don't do that!  It makes working with your dates very hard.  Just store as a `datetime` and then my answer should work out of the box.

Comment: YES, don't do it if you are the table designer. But, You can use the two integer values to assemble a date datatype and then use the between comparison.  there are many ways to do that, but without a year value you will have to assume the same year.